# Mouse Cursor in C++ Not Changing When Loaded

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to change the cursor image in my c++ file. For some reason it isn't working when I execute the program. I used the LoadCursorFromFile and SetCursor methods but something is clearly wrong. I have included the problematic portion of the code. Any help is much appreciated in advance! Thanks for your time.

problematic code

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    HCURSOR cursor = LoadCursorFromFile("mouse.cur");
    HCURSOR SetCursor(cursor);
    MSG msg;
    int counter = 1;
    int posx = 0;
    int posy = 0;
    int seriesinc = 0;
    int arrays;
    int xPos, yPos;
```

Comment: From the docs, referring to mousing over a window: "If the class cursor is not NULL, the system restores the class cursor each time the mouse is moved." You can then use `WM_SETCURSOR` (handle that message). Again, see the docs.

Comment: Indeed, using `SetCursor()` at the beginning of `WinMain()` is especially futile, as the process doesn't even have any window at that time.

Comment: I think you need to read a win32 primer, because there's more wrong with your code than right!

Answer (score 4):

This is a variable declaration, not a function call:

```
HCURSOR SetCursor(cursor);
```

What you wanted was either

```
::SetCursor(cursor); // discard return value
```

or

```
HCURSOR prevCursor = ::SetCursor(cursor);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried replacing the HCURSOR SetCursor(cursor); line with HCURSOR prevCursor = ::SetCursor(cursor); but it didn't work either. Out of curiosity, what is prevCursor and how does this line help in changing the cursor. If you have any other ideas I would love to hear them or if you know why the line doesn't work I would love to hear from you. Thanks again for your answer and your time!

Comment: @user3288629 You should handle it inside `WndProc` method as what @Mark Ransom says

Answer (score 1):

Your window will respond to [`WM_SETCURSOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages by setting the cursor to the default arrow. You may have seen that the cursor changed for just an instant after calling `SetCursor` before changing back - that was the time between the call and the next `WM_SETCURSOR` message.

You should create a handler for the `WM_SETCURSOR` message and call `SetCursor` there, then return `TRUE`.

Comment: You should have also mentioned to do this in inside `WinProc`

Comment: @mr5 I assumed a basic understanding of how to respond to a Windows message.

Comment: @mr5 Mark's answer is correct as written. Your suggestion to restrict where a message should be handled is wrong. There is no such requirement that a message **must** be handled inside your `WndProc`. If you have a specific reason to do so, you can handle it inside your message loop as well, or inside a message hook.